# Python + rope: setting ignored resource patterns?

Tags: python, rope

The [rope documentation](https://github.com/python-rope/rope/blob/master/docs/library.rst) says that:

> Each project has a set of ignored resource patterns

But nowhere does it mention how to configure that list.

How do I configure the list of ignored resources for my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `~/.ropeproject/config.py` there's an `ignored_resources` setting which seems to do the trick:

```
# Specify which files and folders to ignore in the project.
# Changes to ignored resources are not added to the history and
# VCSs.  Also they are not returned in `Project.get_files()`.
# Note that ``?`` and ``*`` match all characters but slashes.
# '*.pyc': matches 'test.pyc' and 'pkg/test.pyc'
# 'mod*.pyc': matches 'test/mod1.pyc' but not 'mod/1.pyc'
# '.svn': matches 'pkg/.svn' and all of its children
# 'build/*.o': matches 'build/lib.o' but not 'build/sub/lib.o'
# 'build//*.o': matches 'build/lib.o' and 'build/sub/lib.o'
prefs['ignored_resources'] = ['*.pyc', '*~', '.ropeproject',
                              '.hg', '.svn', '_svn', '.git', '.tox']
```

Answer (score 0):

Every project has a hidden subdirectory `.ropeproject/`. Take a look at the `config.py` file there. The file is very well documented.