# How to ignore a folder when refactoring in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Say `./` is open in vscode and I have 2 files:

```
# ./good/happy.py
aa = 123
```

and

```
#./bad/sad.py
# This file exists in my project tree and I cannot change it
asdfasdf 86855  arg
```

Trying to rename `aa` fails with `Refactor failed. Syntax error in file <bad/sad.py> line <1>: invalid syntax`. How can I work around this? Simply ignoring `./bad` would work, but I cannot find a way to do this. **How do I get refactoring to work?**

---

[Python + rope: setting ignored resource patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745720/python-rope-setting-ignored-resource-patterns) seems possibly related but the answer didn't "just work".

Looks like there was a related issue: [Respect the "files.exclude" setting when using rope to refactor.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12287)
, but it was closed with "we plan to remove support for rope" in July 2020. However rope still seems to be in use and causing me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer to the surface question, but I did figure out a solution to the core problem. Therefore I'm self answering with a kind of non answer in hopes it helps some one else thinking like this.

As suggested in a comment in that issue, **using a language server other than Jedi** allows refactoring to work. However I was no longer seeing lint warnings so that alone wasn't a fix.

After changing servers, I had to explicitly enable pylint. [ref](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13315#issuecomment-701913450)

settings.json:

```
{
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "python.linting.pylintUseMinimalCheckers": false,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
}
```